# Prove that (0, 1) and (0, 1) ∪ (2, 3) ∪ (4, 5) ∪ .... have same size

Tags: discrete-mathematics, infinity

I first had an idea of splitting (0, 1) into parts of ($\frac{1}{2^n}$,$\frac {1}{2^{n+1}}$ and mapping these to (2, 3) ∪ (4, 5) ∪ ... and the remaining {1/2, 1/4, 1/8, ...} to be mapped to (0, 1), but I can't seem to write it as a proof.

Can someone please guide me on how to do so, or how else to approach the problem?

Comment: "Size" is misleading here, as it could be mistaken for "length" or measure. Your question is about cardinality, right?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: A rather convenient theorem is that if you can find an injective function both ways (i.e. show that each of them is smaller or equal cardinality to the other), then there is a bijection between them (i.e. they have the same size).

Comment: @GyroGearloose yeah, my bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a bijection of $\mathbb{R}$ with $(0,1)$ (like $\mathbb{R}\ni x\mapsto\frac{1}{1+e^{x}}\in (0,1)$) and consider the inclusion of $\bigcup_{n} (n,n+1)$ into $\mathbb{R}$.
Using that $(0,1)$ is included into the union, the conclusion follows from Schröder-Bernstein theorem.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.* Consider $$x\mapsto \frac1x-1$$

Answer (score 1):

You can map $(0,1)\mapsto (0,1]$ like this:

Send $\frac 12\to 1$, now there is a hole in $\frac 12$ so send $\frac 14\to\frac 12$, and so on: $\quad\cdots\to \frac 18\to\frac 14\to\frac 12\to 1$

We can write it $\quad\phi(x):\begin{cases}2x& x=2^{-k}& \forall k\in\mathbb N\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Similarly you can map $(n,n+1)\mapsto(n,n+1]$ and now you can use your initial idea to map the union to $(0,1)$, the stitching issue is now solved.